# Receiving error after removing Option from Select using Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have a `select` element that I am adding `option`'s to with js via an `input` text field. The value must be four digits and this part works fine. I can switch between the `options` to display information for each one also. This is done with the `ctcSelect.addEventListener` function. Everything works fine until I remove a selected option from the 'options' node list. Now my `ctcSelect.addEventListener` function seems to want to change both `i` and `i+1` to true. Of course this throws and error when clicking on the last `option` it also changes two of the `option` custom attributes to `true`.

Hopefully someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```js
let ctcInput = document.getElementById("ctcInput");
let ctcSelect = document.getElementById("ctcSelect");
let removeButton = document.getElementById("removeButton");
let options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

ctcInput.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (isNaN(ctcInput.value) || ctcInput.value.length != 4) return;
  if (e.code == "Enter" || e.code === "Tab") {
    addCtc(Number(ctcInput.value));
  }
});

removeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].dataset.active == "true") rmvCtc(options[i].value);
  }
});

ctcSelect.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log(options);
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    options[i].setAttribute("data-active", "false"); //set all to false if there's a change
    options[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
      options[i].setAttribute("data-active", "true"); //set the clicked one to true
    });
  }
});

function addCtc(ctcNum) {
  if (ctcSelect.length > 6) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (ctcNum == options[i].value) {
      return; //number already exist
    }
  }
  let num = options.length;
  let option = new Option(ctcNum + "", ctcNum);
  if (options.length === 0) {
    option.setAttribute("data-active", "true");
  } else {
    option.setAttribute("data-active", "false");
  }
  ctcSelect.add(option, undefined);
}

function rmvCtc(ctcNum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == ctcNum) {
      options[i].remove();
    }
  }
  if (options.length > 0) options[0].setAttribute("data-active", "true");
}
```

```css
#ctcSelect {
    width: 70px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <lable for="ctcInput">Add CtC #</lable>
  <input type="text" id="ctcInput" name="ctcInput" class="input_boxes">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="ctcSelect">Select Contact</lable>
    <select name="ctcSelect" id="ctcSelect" class="input_boxes"></select>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="removeButton">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Running your code, I do not see any error. When does this happen `Everything works fine until I remove a selected option from the 'options' node list. Now my ctcSelect.addEventListener function seems to want to change both i and i+1 to true. Of course this throws and error when clicking on the last option it also changes two of the option custom attributes to true.`

Comment: Try this. Add 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114 and then remove 1112. Now when you select 1113 and if you console log options you'll notice both 1113 and 1114 data-active are set to true. 1114 in this case would be `i + 1`. If you select 1114 you'll get an error that `options[i]` is undefined because its trying to set `i+1` for some reason. I can't figure out why it does this only after I remove an option. There should be no `i + 1`. It should only change `i` or the selected number.

Comment: `options[i].addEventListener("click", …)` inside another event listener is a very bad idea

Comment: Also you have the problem that `document.getElementsByTagName("option")` returns a live node list. `options[i]` will not always refer to the same element, but rather to the `i`th currently attached element.

Comment: Please explain further. If I console log `options` prior to the ‘for’ loop shows the correct number of elements. If I console Log `i` It displays 0, 1, 2. Why does it work fine before removing an option from the node list? If the node list is 5 option elements and the for loop iterates 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Then why is it trying to set options[5] when `i` Is never 5?

Comment: @Bergi I found a much cleaner way to write the function out using `selectedIndex` on the node list vice using a loop and trying to identify which one I selected. This also gets rid of the second eventListener. Hopefully it works in the bigger project.

Comment: @Justin "*If I console log `options` prior to the ‘for’ loop shows the correct number of elements.*" - yes, but if you log it again inside the click handler it might have a different number of elements (or different elements, or in different order etc) by then. It might actually work as you designed if you did store the value of `options[i]` in a local variable during the loop, and then referred to that in the click event handler.